# Show values in Matlab depending on previous values in another column

Tags: matlab, dependencies, row, calculated-columns

I'm struggling with the following problem in Matlab:

I’ve got a table containing a few column vectors: Day, Name, Result
My goal is to create another column vector (**New vector**) that shows me in each row the result of the previous day for the corresponding name.

```
| Day | Name | Result | New Vector |
|-----|------|--------|------------|
| 1   | A    | 1.2    | 0          |
| 1   | C    | 0.9    | 0          |
| 1   | B    | 0.7    | 0          |
| 1   | D    | 1.1    | 0          |
| 2   | B    | 1      | 0.7        |
| 2   | A    | 1.5    | 1.2        |
| 2   | C    | 1.4    | 0.9        |
| 2   | D    | 0.9    | 1.1        |
| 3   | B    | 1.1    | 1          |
| 3   | C    | 1.3    | 1.4        |
| 3   | A    | 1      | 1.5        |
| 3   | D    | 0.3    | 0.9        |
```

For example **row 5**:

It is **day 2** and name is **"B"**. The vector **"RESULT"** shows **1.0** in the same row but what I want to show in my new vector, is the result value of **"B"** of the **previous day** (**day 1** in this example). 
Since one can find **"B"** on the previous day in **row 3**, the **result** value is **0.7**, which should be shown in **row 5** of my New Vector.

When day is equal to 1, the logical consequence is that there are no values since there is no previous day. Consequently I want to show 0 for each row on Day 1.

I've already tried some combinations of unique to get the index and some if clauses but it did not work at all since I'm relatively new to Matlab and still very confused.

Is anybody able to help? Thank you so much!!

Comment: This sounds like a solution requiring a loop. What have you tried?

Comment: I've edited my original post, please have a look.

Comment: It seems your data is in an inconvenient format. It would be much simpler if your `Result` values were in a 2d array with a row for each day and a column for each name. Then your exercise would be reduced to adding a 0 row at the top and deleting the bottom row.

Comment: Please note that I want to keep this structure. It does not help to shift those values since the order of the values on day Y depends on the order of the values on day X.

Comment: It is very difficult to help, as your question is not well defined. I highly recommend that you upload your code, no matter how bad it is. Your descriptions are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not well defined, but the code below solves your problem as it is stated.

This code works by internally sorting each Day's information in order of Name. This allows New Vector to be created easily by simply shifting and then inverting the sort operation.

```
close all; clear all; clc;

% A few column vectors
Day = [1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3];
Name = ['A';'C';'B';'D';'B';'A';'C';'D';'B';'C';'A';'D'];
Result = [1.2;0.9;0.7;1.1;1;1.5;1.4;0.9;1.1;1.3;1;0.3];

% Sort the table (so Name is in order for each Day)
[~,Index] = sort(max(Name)*Day + Name);
Day = Day(Index);
Name = Name(Index);
Result = Result(Index);

% Shift Result to get sorted NewVector
NewVector = circshift(Result, 4);
NewVector(1:4) = 0;

% Unsort NewVector, to get original table ordering
ReverseIndex(Index) = 1:length(Index);
NewVector = NewVector(ReverseIndex)
```

This prints the following result:

```
NewVector =

         0
         0
         0
         0
    0.7000
    1.2000
    0.9000
    1.1000
    1.0000
    1.4000
    1.5000
    0.9000
```